# Android Studio Libgdx Memory problems

Tags: android, memory, libgdx

I have some problems with my app. Sometimes it lags and gives me "GC_CONCURRENT freed". I use MAT to look what consumes so much memory and I found out that a list of objects eats a lot of memory. The problem is that I have blocks in my game and I need to see if my player steps on them so that's why I am using this list. I currently have 200 blocks, but I will have much more and I don't think they should use so much memory, what can I do to fix the problem? This is how the block class looks:

```
package com.NeverMind.DontFall.android;

import android.util.Log;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

/**
 * Created by user on 20-Aug-15.
 */
public class blockClass {
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    public float x, y, sizeX = 100, sizeY = 100, startTime;
    private boolean isTouched = false;
    private Texture texture;
    Sprite blockSprite;
    public blockClass(float sentX, float sentY, Texture sentTexture, float scaleX, float scaleY){
        x = sentX;
        y = sentY;
        sizeY *= scaleY;
        sizeX *= scaleX;
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
        texture = sentTexture;
        blockSprite = new Sprite(texture);
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    public void draw(float cameraX, float cameraY) {
        spriteBatch.begin();
        spriteBatch.draw(blockSprite, x + cameraX, y + cameraY, sizeX, sizeY);
        spriteBatch.end();
    }
    public void update(float posX, float posY, boolean immune){
        if (isTouched == false && immune == false)
            if (touched(posX, posY) )
                isTouched = true;
        if (isTouched == true) {
            y -= 10;
        }
    }
    public boolean touched (float posX, float posY)
    {
        if (posX >= x && posX < x + sizeX && posY == y + sizeY)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public boolean toKill (float posY){
        if (isTouched && y < posY - 1000)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you create your 200 blocks ?before starting game or in runtime?

Comment: It is a global variable so the list is created when the game starts, but only once. After the list is created, I put the objects in it in create() method, which runs only once.

Comment: Do you kill objects while game is rendering?

Comment: Yes, when I no longer need that object.

Comment: So every one of your blocks instantiates a SpriteBatch?!! You should only have one SpriteBatch in your entire game, and reuse it for all objects. SpriteBatch uses significant native memory and it is entirely redundant to have more than one of them. And by the way, it must have `dispose` called on it before you lose it from scope to the GC.

Comment: You should use pooling as @Saeed's answer says. But the reason you're seeing stutters even with just a few blocks lost is because each SpriteBatch has a big array in it. So it doesn't take very many lost blocks to trigger the GC. Also, every copy of SpriteBatch compiles its own shader. I think some mobile devices may have difficulties with 200 compiled shaders!

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks for this lovely info. didnt knew this about spritebatch, probably be cause i never used more than one spritebatch

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you, man. Didn't know SpriteBatch destroys so much memory.

Answer (score 5):

`GC_CONCURRENT freed` means that Garbage Collector is called, because of killing objects (e.g assign `null` to them).

There is a concept calls [Object Pooling](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management), it reuses dead object instead of kill it and obtain object from pool instead of creating a new one, So you have no GC calls and similarly no `GC_CONCURRENT freed`.

Comment: Are you sure about this? You might misunderstood, I don't think it is supposed to pause my game, which causes the lag, eg: GC_CONCURRENT freed 355K, 15% free 11033K/12935K, paused 17ms+2ms, total 58ms

Comment: Yes i'm sure pooling is a common way to avoid gc calls. As your comment "Yes, when I no longer need that object. " you are calling gc by killing your objects

Comment: gdx gives its own pool class if u dont want to use that u can write  your own logic. as a thumb rule my number of object is the maximum number of object active at one time plus 3 more to avoid any null pointers and then play with them to assign them and thus saving memeory and gc calls. one example can be a bullet in a shotting game if i make a new object everytime and then make it null then gc will lag game so better reuse the bullet when its scope on display screen is over